# Is there a framework that can push bulk data?

Tags: hadoop

Our MySQL and Hadoop platform are deployed in different network, Hadoop cannot visit MySQL but MySQL can connect to Hadoop.

So is there a tool that can push bulk data from RDS to HDFS like Sqoop fetch data? or is there any other method that can address this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

---

By the way, the Hadoop cluster consumes a Kafka topic in our network by deploying flume in both sides and connect together. But for bulk RDS data, how to achieve this?

Comment: This is referred to more broadly as "data ingestion".  There are a lot of technologies that help with this beyond SQOOP, Kafka and Flume.

Answer (score 0):

Here for movement of bulk data from MySQL to Hadoop, you have another option/Solution i.e. Spark JDBC connection to MySQL database to bring data into Hadoop cluster.

Use of Sqoop for data movement is old technique to import data from RDBMS to hadoop cluster. But SparkJDBC solution is based on Spark in memory execution engine with well proven performance record and reliable to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But our network does not have and will not build a Hadoop cluster. So is there any other option?

Comment: It doesn't matter what are the Platforms for Hadoop and MySQL, as far as MySQL is accessible from Hadoop edge node it will connect to MySQL. Are you looking for Hadoop solution or something else?

Comment: In my case, Hadoop cannot access MySQL but MySQL can access Hadoop. So I'm looking for a non-Hadoop solution that can send bulk data from MySQL to HDFS.